# How to reference childs of multiple children of a json-response

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, axios

I'm currently trying to fetch data of my `firebase-realtime-database` using `axios`for my `react-native` app. The goal is to have multiple cards in my app that have the values "latitude", "longitude", "name", "price" and an image on them. To render the cards I use the map-function.

I wrote a `google-cloud-functions` to get the data from my database:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
  admin.database().ref('locations/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    res.send(snapshot.val());
  }, err => res.send({ error: err }));
}
```

which responds is the following:

```
{
     "-LXd6BopD1onEMc--1qS": {
        "latitude": xxxx,
        "longitude": xxxx,
        "name": "xxxx",
        "price": "xxx",
        "url": "xxxxx"
    },
    "-LXd7GokGQqkxkhDXJBd": {
        "latitude": xxxx,
        "longitude": xxxx,
        "name": "xxxx",
        "price": "xxxx",
        "url": "xxxxxx"
    },
}
```

The key/name of the child is basically unknown, since I'm using "push" to put data into the database, which creates unique keys for each entry.

I'm currently using this to get access to the data, but unfortunately "data" is always undefined.

```
let { data } = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/getValues`)
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why is "data" undefined and how can I fix it?
2. If the first question is solved, how do I get the data out of both children since I don't explicitly know their keys. How do I reference them?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can we see the Functions code ?

Comment: What is the actual result of the axios request? Rather than destructuring it. To deal with the second problem you could use `Object.keys(data)` that will give you an array of keys you could then iterate over them pulling out each object from the data and converting it to what ever you wished.

Comment: @Andrew the result of the request is the code after "which respond is the following". I tested this with postman.

Comment: @cutiko I just updated my post with the firebase-function

Comment: So you are saying that if you make the following request `let response = await axios.get(${ROOT_URL}/getValues)` then `reponse = { "-LXd6BopD1onEMc--1qS" : {...}, "-LXd7GokGQqkxkhDXJBd" : {...}}`?

Comment: Change on for once, on is for a real time listener once is for a one time query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So For the **second question** the JSON you are receiving looks like

```
{
     "-LXd6BopD1onEMc--1qS": {
        "latitude": xxxx,
        "longitude": xxxx,
        "name": "xxxx",
        "price": "xxx",
        "url": "xxxxx"
    },
    "-LXd7GokGQqkxkhDXJBd": {
        "latitude": xxxx,
        "longitude": xxxx,
        "name": "xxxx",
        "price": "xxxx",
        "url": "xxxxxx"
    },
}
```

Keys that are generated by firebase are `-LXd6BopD1onEMc--1qS` and your data object is against these keys.

Do get the data object you have to reference your data by using the key.

suppose the JSON you received is in `data` variable, then either you can use `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` do get keys and the your data object from the `data` variable. Or you can use *"for in"* loop

```
var data = {....}  // this data variable holds the json response you received

for (var key in data) {
  var myObj = data[key];
  console.log(myObj);        // object of your data
  console.log(myObj.name);   // name
  console.log(myObj.price);  // price
}
```

Also remember you can reference the keys by two ways

either `myObj.name` or `myObj['name']` depends on the name of your keys. Second one is useful when your keys are not valid javascript variable names.

For the **First question** would be nice if you will provide the request, response code snippets.

Otherwise this line

```
let { data } = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/getValues`)
```

in your question should technically work fine provided url is right or otherwise use try catch around it and catch and log error or try to console the response you receive.

Answer (score 0):

1.- `await axios.get('${ROOT_URL}/getValues')`  this code returns a promise, so you still need to resolve that promise to get the data back from it

2.- One you get the data back, you can iterate it with Object.keys or Object.entries. See the code snippet

Hope this helps

```js
async function request(){
return  await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
}

async function makeRequest() {

const {data} = await request(); // this line resolves the promise
console.log(data);

}

makeRequest();


const dummyResponse = {
     "-LXd6BopD1onEMc--1qS": {
        "latitude": 'xxxx',
        "longitude": 'xxxx',
        "name": "xxxx",
        "price": "xxx",
        "url": "xxxxx"
    },
    "-LXd7GokGQqkxkhDXJBd": {
        "latitude": 'xxxx',
        "longitude": 'xxxx',
        "name": "xxxx",
        "price": "xxxx",
        "url": "xxxxxx"
    },
};

Object.keys(dummyResponse).forEach( key => {console.log(key)})
Object.entries(dummyResponse).forEach( entry => {console.log(entry)})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```